# Make DATEDIFF of Redshift behave as TIMESTAMPDIFF of MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-redshift

In `MYSQL`, `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2016-01-31', '2016-02-01')` returns `0`.

In `Redshift`, `DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2016-01-31', '2016-02-01')` returns `1`.

How do I make the `DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2016-01-31', '2016-02-01')` in `Redshift` to return `0`?

Currently I am using `DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-01-31', '2016-02-01')/30`. But this is not good enough as some months have 28-31 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MONTHS_BETWEEN` is a good solution to this problem.

Example:

```
select months_between('1969-03-18', '1969-01-18') as months;
```

You can read more about this in the redshift [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MONTHS_BETWEEN_function.html).